# ERROR Error: Value is undefined in lightweight charts

Tags: angular, tradingview-api, lightweight-charts

I am getting this error in my project where I am using the library lightweight charts.

```
 ERROR Error: Value is undefined
    at ensureDefined (lightweight-charts.development.mjs:199:15)
    at ChartApi._private__mapSeriesToApi (lightweight-charts.development.mjs:12846:16)
    at ChartApi._private__convertMouseParams (lightweight-charts.development.mjs:12862:94)
    at Object._internal_callback (lightweight-charts.development.mjs:12703:75)
    at lightweight-charts.development.mjs:524:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Delegate._internal_fire (lightweight-charts.development.mjs:524:27)
    at ChartWidget._private__onPaneWidgetCrosshairMoved (lightweight-charts.development.mjs:11444:39)
    at lightweight-charts.development.mjs:524:58
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

**What I have checked:**

1. I made sure that no values are null in the data of the series.
2. I made sure of a chart or series won't be undefined.

If someone has faced the same value and can provide the solution then it'll be appreciated.

**Edited:**
I found that, this error is reported as issue in lightweight charts github. [check here](https://github.com/tradingview/lightweight-charts/issues/1499)

Thank you.

Comment: please share the code, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated